# CTRL + C not being caught

Tags: go, operating-system, signals

I am trying to write a program which prints "wait" whenever cntrl + c is being pressed and continue printing the numbers from 1 to 10. Otherwise, numbers from 1 to 10 should be printed with delay of 10 seconds between each number.However control+ c is not being recognized whenever i click and "wait" is not being printed only numbers from 1 to 10 are.

```
    func main() {
        c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
        signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
        go func() {
            for sig := range c {
                fmt.Print(sig)
                fmt.Print("WAIT")
            }
        }()
        for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println(i)
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }

}
```

Comment: It works for me (Linux, Go 1.11).

Comment: your go function probably finishes before you can press ctrl + c, you probably want an infinite loop to catch the signal

Comment: Please include the output of `go version` and `go env`. Also, what does `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0)` return to you?

Comment: it works for me too. How did you run the go program?

Comment: The program works for me on Linux and MacOs with go 1.10.3

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? What shell are you using? I've experienced this same issue before in Cygwin but it works perfectly when using PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that your terminal or terminal emulator settings are set up to do what you are trying to do. Terminal drivers do a lot of filtering. For example on Enunchs,  keys get translated into  sent to the application and then get echoed back to the terminal as as .

Your terminal driver could be just ignoring . It could be in a passthu mode where it just sends  as a character to your application.

How you would make such settings depends upon your operating system.